# Cannot find name 'provide'

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, karma-runner

When i use the Mock to test the Angular,why 'provide' cannot be find.

```html
 beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers : [
      provide(StrategyTablesService,{useClass:MockstrategyService})
        ]
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have to use an object `provide` instead the function

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [{ 
      provide: StrategyTablesService, useClass: MockstrategyService }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use angular.mock.module()

```
beforeEach(() => {
  angular.mock.module(($provide) => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        $provide.value(StrategyTablesService, { useClass:MockstrategyService });
      ]
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: the angular is also cannot be find...why?

Comment: import * as angular from 'angular';

Comment: But...Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'.